# Expected number of trials before first success

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

I have a question which I hope statistics experts on this forum can help me with.

Given a time series data *D(t)* with mean *m* and median *M* what is the expected time (number of trials) before value *y* is encountered for the first time after value *x* is encountered.

For example, if given numbers 2,5,2,6,3,7,6,3 (with discrete time starting at 1 with time step 1) and x=2 and y=6 the answer to this question with this data would be 2.66 ((3+1+4)/3 = 2.66).

I am looking for a statistical solution as opposed to an algorithm to calculate this.

Apologies in advance if something is not fully defined.

Comment: In the example, why do you count distance 4 since in 26376, the last 6 is not "encountered for the first time after value 2 is encountered"?

Comment: I don't think I understand your example. Can you explain how you get $3$, $1$ and $4$? (Why don't you have $6$ if you have $4$?)

Comment: Did/Tunococ - agree with you both distance 4 is not relevant. I get 3 as distance between the first 2 and 6 and 1 as distance between second 2 and first 6.

Comment: Is the distribution of the time series known?

Answer (score 0):

Let $T_n$ denote the time when the $n$th time value $x$ is observed, and $T_n+D_n$ the first time after $T_n$ when the value $y\ne x$ is observed. For every $N\geqslant1$, let $\nu_N=\sup\{n\geqslant1\mid T_n+D_n\leqslant N\}$. The question seems to ask for the limit when $N\to\infty$ of
$$
E[\Delta_N\mid\nu_N\geqslant1],\qquad\text{where}\ \Delta_N=\frac1{\nu_N}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\nu_N}D_n.
$$
Assuming that the letters produced are i.i.d. and uniform on an alphabet of size $a$, each random variable $D_n$ is geometrically distributed, with $P[D_n\geqslant k]=\left(\frac{a-1}a\right)^{k-1}$ for every $k\geqslant1$, but the random variables $(D_n)$ might not be independent--hence one would like some confirmation from the OP that this is the model considered, or not, before going any further.

Comment: Did - this is indeed the model being considered with one exception - the the values produced are not i.i.d nor uniform. The value generating function is dependent on the last value produced with probability of it being the same highest and further away - lowest, i.e. if the last value was 6 the next one is more likely to be 6 again rather than a 10. Any simple function that describes this relationship will do for the purposes of this question.